# WCF netTcpBinding Windows security EncryptAndSign

Tags: wcf, nettcpbinding

I'm using netTcpBinding with "Transport" security ("Windows" credentials & "EncryptAndSign" protection).
I already know that Kerberos (after SPNEGO) is used to authenticate client & server (both machines on the same Windows domain).
I'd like to know what is/are the algorythm(s) used then to encrypt and sign the TCP Transport channel since there is no config choice ("Message" security has "algorithmSuite" config parameter but it's not available for "Transport" security)

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

The NetTcpBinding class uses TCP for message transport. Security for the transport mode is provided by implementing Transport Layer Security (TLS) over TCP. The TLS implementation is provided by the operating system.

You can also specify the client's credential type by setting the ClientCredentialType property of the TcpTransportSecurity class to one of the TcpClientCredentialType values, as shown in the following code.

C#

```
NetTcpBinding b = new NetTcpBinding();
b.Security.Mode = SecurityMode.Transport;
b.Security.Transport.ClientCredentialType =
     TcpClientCredentialType.Certificate;
```

More info can be found here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms729700

Hope that helps.